# Are microframeworks intended for large code bases?

Tags: web-frameworks

I ask about the longevity of microframeworks like Flask, Bottle, and expressjs. Advantages: small, fast, manageable.

Are they intended to be replaced as code complexity and user base grow? Also asked: should they be replaced with a full framework like Django or Pyramid, or are microframeworks the new standard?

Comment: Very open-ended question. As much as I like the question and its answers here below, I don't think it's *entirely* in the spirit of SO. I will not vote to close it though, I think people close too many questions both left and right. Instead I wrote this comment. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it kind of depends on what you mean by growth.  Let's look at two possibilities:

1. User growth.  If you're building an application with fairly fixed features which you expect to have a rapidly expanding user-base (like Twitter), then a microframework may be ideally suited for scalability since it's already stripped down to the bare essentials + your application code.
2. Feature growth.  If you have a site which you're expecting to require rapid addition of many discrete and complex yet generic features (forums, messaging, commerce, mini-applications, plugins, complex APIs, blogs), then you may save time by using a full-featured framework like Django or Ruby on Rails.

Basically, the only reason a microframework might be unsuitable for your application in the long term is if you think you would benefit from plug-and-play functionality.  Because fully-featured frameworks are higher-level than microframeworks, you'll often find fully-featured solutions as plugins right out of the box.  Blogs, authentication, and so on.  With microframeworks you're expected to roll your own solutions for these things, but with access to a lot of lower-level functionality through the community.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what the (micro)framework supports, as well as the amount of documentation provided for it.

For example, a site using Flask needs a database for storing data. Even though Flask does not have a database extension built in, there are extensions available for it.

Answer (score 0):

If the microframework can handle it why replace it with something else?

Comment: I'm not sure what becomes of large sites using a microframework. Does the framework fail to suffice in some way?

Comment: Large is a relative term and could mean a lot of different things to different people. If the framework is up for the task and the site performs well with it then there is likely no reason to change. If the site outgrows the framework due to limitations or forces imposed that would outweigh the benefit of sticking with it then it's probably okay to move to another framework. I'd invest some time during the requirements gathering to see if there is any potential issues that may arise down the road by using one of the microframeworks.